# Quartz scheduler: avoid using class file and want to call a method directly

Tags: c#, asp.net, quartz-scheduler

I am using quartz scheduler in my project. I have copy pasted my code below.In this area of code, 
     `Type type=typeof(class)`,
I need to call a method like, 
    `Type type=typeof(methodname())`.
I dont want to call an external class file.

```
int JobID = 0;
JobDetailImpl job = null;
Quartz.Impl.Triggers.CronTriggerImpl trigger = null;
ISimpleTrigger simpleTrigger = null;
JobDataMap jobdatamap = new JobDataMap();
sheduler.Start();
String cronExpression = "0 0/1 * * * ?";
Type type = typeof(TriggerJob1);
job = new JobDetailImpl("Job" + JobID + "", null, type);
trigger = new Quartz.Impl.Triggers.CronTriggerImpl("Trigger" + JobID + "", "Job" + JobID + "", cronExpression);
sheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

TriggerJob1 in the above code is a class file which I created locally. According to quartz scheduler, it has the functionality that scheduler calls at its scheduled time.

why i want to use a method instead of Triggerjob1 class file is:- I am using quartz scheduler in aspx file. I have all functionality written in a button click event. I am going to invoke this button by using scheduler.

I want to use like this. This is my expected behaviour.

```
Type type = typeof(button_click);
```

I do not want to call this button click from external class file. But the syntax of quartz scheduler advices me to use a class file only.

Kindly help me if anyone know it. If anyone cannot understand me what I am saying, please let me know.

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/a/38891315/5836671

Comment: NO that was different case.

Comment: Why would you want to schedule a button click? The code inside the `button_click` function can be copied to a function that is called by the scheduler: `void IJob.Execute(IJobExecutionContext context) { myFunction(); }`